# Proof of if two random variables have the same distribution then they have the same moment generating function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to prove that if $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, then they have the same moment generating function: $M_X(t) = M_Y(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I came up with a proof, but am not sure if it is correct:

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution $F$. Then, the moment generating function for $X$ and $Y$ is: $M_X(t) = E(e^{tX})$ and $M_Y(t) = E(e^{tY})$.

Now, for the general case:

$$
M_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{tx}dF(x). 
$$
and 
$$
M_X(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ty}dF(y). 
$$

But, since these two integrals differ only by indices, $M_X(t) = M_Y(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

I tried looking into a proof by contradiction but was not able to formulate one. The above seems a bit too simple, does anyone have any ideas as to if it is correct or alternate proofs? Thanks!

Comment: This seems fine, but then again I'm no expert.

Comment: It is as simple as that.

Comment: Yes, moment generating function, by definition, depends only on the distribution of random variable.

Comment: **If** one has a mgf, then so does the other, and they are the same. But the mgf may not exist.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Your second integral ought to be $M_Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $M_X(t)$ and $M_Y(t)$ [exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Introduction). Then assuming the pdfs exist

$$M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tx} f_X(x)dx$$

$$M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{ty} f_Y(y)dy$$

Let's rewrite the arguments:

$$M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tz} f_X(z)dz$$

$$M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tz} f_Y(z)dz$$

We are given that (or can deduce from $F_X(z) = F_Y(z)$)

$$f_X(z) = f_Y(z)$$

Hence we can rewrite $M_Y(t)$

$$M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}] = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{tz} f_X(z)dz$$

$$\therefore, M_Y(t) = M_X(t) \ QED$$

---

If the pdfs don't exist, we replace $f_{*}dx$ w/ $dF_{*}(x)$

Comment: The existence of the PDFs $f_X$ and $f_Y$ is not guaranteed and not needed.