# Two random variables have the same $n^{th}$ moment for all $n\geq 0$. Then they have the same distribution

Tags: probability-theory, moment-problem

I am working this question:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be $[0,1]-$valued random variables such that $E[X^{n}]=E[Y^{n}]$ for every integer $n\geq 0$. Show that $E[f(X)]=E[f(Y)]$ for every continuous function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and conclude that $X=_{d}Y$. (Hint: use the Weierstrass approximation theorem)

Similar questions have been posted here:[Show two random variables have same distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238475/show-two-random-variables-have-same-distribution)

and here: [Proof of if two random variables have the same distribution then they have the same moment generating function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485627/proof-of-if-two-random-variables-have-the-same-distribution-then-they-have-the-s)

However, it seems that this question is asking me firstly to prove $E[f(X)]=E[f(Y)]$ for every continuous function, and then use this fact to deduce they have the same distribution.

The Weierstrass approximation theorem is here:

> If $f$ is a real-valued function on $[a,b]$ and if any $\epsilon>0$ is given, then there exists a polynomial $P$ on $[a,b]$ such that $|f(x)-P(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

So firstly I show that $n^{th}$ moment of random variable is always a polynomial? Even if I showed this, it seems that the argument is backward.

Answer with some more details will be really appreciated since I got really lost...

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

As what the comment suggested, I should show $E[p(X)]=E[p(Y)]$ for all polynomial. However, I am reading Durrett, and there is nothing related to the relation between $n^{th}$ moment of a random variable and the expectation of a polynomial. I don't really know what to do here.

Also, as I pointed out in the comment of the first answer, if I know they have the same $n^{th}$ moment for each $n$, then using series expansion to the moment generating function immediately yields me that they have the same moment generating function and thus they have the same distribution. So why would I need to deduce this fact from $E[f(X)]=E[f(Y)]$?

Comment: First Show that if $p$ is a polynomial then $E[p(X)] = E[p(Y)]$. Then think about why this helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an arbitrary polynomial $p(x) = c_n x^n + c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+ \dots + c$. Then

$$
\mathbb{E}[p(X)] = c_n\mathbb{E}[X^n] + c_{n-1} \mathbb{E}[X^{n-1}] + \dots + c = \\
c_n\mathbb{E}[Y^n] + c_{n-1} \mathbb{E}[Y^{n-1}] + \dots + c = \mathbb{E}[p(Y)]
$$

Now take any function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and corresponding polynomial $p$ from Weierstrass then

$$
\left|\mathbb{E}[f(X)] - \mathbb{E}[f(Y)]\right| = \\ 
\left|\mathbb{E}[f(X) - p(X) + p(X)] - \mathbb{E}[f(Y) - p(Y) + p(Y)]\right| \leq \\ 2 \epsilon + \underbrace{\left|\mathbb{E}[p(X) - p(Y)] \right|}_{equal} \leq 2 \epsilon
$$

Now since $X,Y$ are bounded the moment generating functions exists and since 
$\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = \mathbb{E}[f(Y)]$. The moment generating functions are equal and hence $X =^{d} Y$

Comment: well if they have the same $n^{th}$ moment for each $n$, then they by series expansion have the same moment generating function so they must have the same distribution, why do I need to take a detour to show these things? Also I don't really know how to show $E[p(X)]=E[p(Y)]$, would you like to provide some details?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Yes the finite series are equal. But how can you be sure that they are equal for an infinite series?

Comment: Yes.. you are right... could you please provide more details of the proof?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical take arbitrary polynomial. Then use linearity of expected value and that constants can be moved outside of the expectation

Comment: I don’t think this is correct, as per this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166637/do-moments-define-distributions

Comment: @Ant X and Y are bounded by 0 and 1. Thus $0 \leq E[e^{\rho |X|}] \leq e^{\rho}$ for any $\rho>0$ and thus (as per comment in your link) we can do this

Comment: Sure, I agree. But your answer doesn’t use that property, so the proof can’t be right

Comment: @Ant not explicity. But I use that X and Y are bounded in order to guarantee that the moment generating function exist.  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/467453/229160

Comment: I don't think we can directly use linearity, if we have $E[p(X)]$ then by the change of variable formula, we have $E[p(X)]=\int p(x)\mu(dx)$, in which $p(x)$ cannot be directly pulled out of the integral.

Comment: oh! That's what you meant..Thank you! Just one question, if I don't want to use the moment generating function, could I set $f(x):=e^{itx}$ which is continuous on $x\in[0,1]$, so that $E[f(X)]=\phi_{X}(t)$ where $\phi_{X}(t)$ is the characteristic function, and then conclude they have the same distribution?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical The characteristic function is a complex valued function and then you are not following the "description" in the problem

Comment: so using moment generating function is the only way? I am just not sure if I need to prove that moment generating function determines the distribution uniquely... which is a long proof.

Comment: I will just use moment generating function. Thank you so much :)